# Java - выполнение команд командной строки и запись её вывода в переменную

Tags: java

Мне нужно выполнить из под Java команду в командной строке, это как сделать я знаю:`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("команда");` Но как записать её вывод в переменную? То есть, если я в команде впишу dir, то её вывод(папки, файлы etc...) будут в переменной. Можно ли это как то реализовать?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)  exec возвращает Process, у которого можно получить InputStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()